# Library to do 2D image manipulation

Tags: gratis, library, software-development, c++, windows-10

I'm looking for a 2D image manipulation library for C++, ideally something modern which uses C++20.

Requirements:

- works on Windows 10 (support for Windows filenames, mainly)
- works with Visual Studio 2022 (no makefiles please)
- simple to include (maybe header only; ideally just a few files), like [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/) if you know that
- produces no or few warnings only, when being comiled
- I only need basic operations like

  - get pixel / set pixel
  - draw line, ellipse and rectangle
- support for PNG files (JPG and BMP welcome), reading and writing
- gratis

Non-requirements:

- displaying images on screen

I have tried:

- [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Install.html)

  - the site says it's up to Windows 7
  - the download location is unclear

    > 'win2k' subdirectory of the ImageMagick ftp site (and mirrors)
  - Visual Studio version is outdated

    > ready-made Visual C++ 8.0 build environment
- [Leptonica](https://github.com/danbloomberg/leptonica)

  - looks very C-ish, not C++-ish

Comment: Hi Thomas.  I haven't tried Magick++ on Win10, but I've heard it will work as expected.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket thanks for the suggestion. I hope I get another task that requires a graphics library so that I can test it as well. For now I implemented it with SFML (see answer below) and I liked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php) to suit my needs.

I really like the method names. They are straight forward, IMHO. Not cryptic or abbreviated.

For the requirements:

- works on Windows 10
- works with Visual Studio 2022.

  The [download site](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/) mentions Visual Studio 2017 as the latest versions, but when I opened an issue on Github, the answer was that the VS2017 version is compatible with VS2019 and VS2022.
- simple to include.

  The [Tutorial for Visual Studio](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php) tells you what you need to do. Basically add some paths so that SFML can be found - stuff you know how to do when doing C++ development in Visual Studio.
- get pixel / set pixel

  The code I used is as simple as

```
    sf::Image buffer;
    buffer.create(size, size, sf::Color(0, 0, 0));
    // some loop here
         buffer.setPixel(x, y, sf::Color::Green);

    buffer.saveToFile("test.png");
```

- support for PNG files (JPG and BMP welcome), reading and writing

  Writing is definitely possible, see code before.
- gratis

  [zlib/png licensed](https://www.sfml-dev.org/license.php)

Displaying an image as a window was not so straight forward. It can't draw images on the window. It needs a sprite for that. And the Sprite needs a texture. I see that this may have benefit in game development and might speed up stuff if textures are reused. So the code is a little more complicated, but still ok:

```
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 1000), "Visualization");

    sf::Image buffer;
    buffer.create(size, size, sf::Color(0, 0, 0));
    // Some loop here
        buffer.setPixel(x, y, sf::Color::Green);

    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.create(size,size);
    texture.update(buffer);

    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(0.f, 0.f));
    sprite.scale(1000.f / size, 1000.f / size);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }
```